# Chrome Developer Tools - Use filter text field to match multiple requests

Tags: regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, filtering

In Chrome Developer Tools, I want to use the filter text field in the Network panel to match multiple requests, for example, to show all requests with names containing either "coda" or "smart".
Also, supposing I have 10 images with names image[0-9].jpg (image0, image1,...image9), what expression do I write to match them all?

I have checked the [Developer Tools documentation on said subject](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#filter), but it didn't help. Also, the regex checkbox in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1FBo.jpg) isn't available in my own developer tools (Chrome 71)

Comment: Press the funnel icon then enter a regexp in slashes: `/image\d\.jpg/`

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks. what about searching for requests with either of two or more words?

Comment: Regexp can do that. You can use https://regex101.com to tweak the query (make sure to select JS mode).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I finally figured it out.
For the first part: /\bcoda|smart\b/

For the second part: /image\d.jpg/

The regex checkbox isn't available because the filter text field already supports regex expressions.